# getting ClassCastException in OSGi standalone framework with JAXB

Tags: jaxb, osgi

I am running OSGi framework through CLI by running command as below:

java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar -console

My plugins run fine but while running my plugin that requires JAXB packages of system library (JavaSE1.6.xx) to parse xml file I am getting exception trace as below:

```
Exception in thread "DummyProgram" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.<clinit>(DatatypeConverter.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:262)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:260)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:260)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
        at com.entities.conf.JAXBMTSConfig.unmarshalApps(JAXBMTSConfig.java:113)
        20 more..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
        at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:742)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a conflict with different versions of `javax.xml.bind.*` packages. I guess they are exported by the System library *and* a xerces (?) jar?

So you'll need to find out which bundle exports those packages, and resolve the conflict.

regards, Frank

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply...
For now I have included xerces JAR and rt JAR to ANOTHER PLUGIN
and exportd those packages EXCEPT javax.xml.datatype,
and wired Up it with all plugins.

So it works fine, but we know that this is not a good approach to include jre system library jars to our osgi plugins..

Is there any other better way to fullfill the requirements of JRE imports at runtime when we run OSGi Framework "Outside Eclipse"..?

Comment: Patel, I'm facing the same issue and I can't understand what you did, Can you please write an answer with all the steps to solve the issue. I will appreciate it and I really think It will help others.

Answer (score 1):

A class-cast exception in OSGi is typically caused by the fact, that every bundle has it's own class loader.
It is possible that two bundles load the same class from other sources (because they are exported twice). Because every bundle has its own class loader, they are loaded by two different class loaders, so java doesn't accept this as the same class.

There are two workarounds:
- check if the class is exported twice. If this is the case, try to solve this by exporting it only once.
This may not be possible, because bundle a may need version 1.4, and bundle b 1.7.

- if this is the case, import the exported class in the bundle.
  So, for example:
  Bundle A exports xyz-1.4 and imports xyz-1.4
  Bundle B exports xyz-1.7 and imports xyz-1.7

Now the framework can decide which class is used. If bundle a runs alone, 1.4 will be used.
Otherwise, Bundle A and B are needed by a Bundle C, 1.7 will be used (in case that it is downward compatible to 1.4)